# The program is not recognizing a selected combobox input as the value for the combobox when I call combobox.get()

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to do certain actions with the value of a combobox whose values are set by another combobox. Although the program runs smoothly and the contents of the second combobox (Students.input) are updated by the selection of the first(Subjects.input), when I call Students.input.get() it returns an empty value.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Gradebook +")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)#Only one column is set, but ensures that form stays centred when expanding
variables = dict()
class Pupil():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.Assignments = {"History Final":{"Weight":5, "Grade":75}, "Washington Essay":{"Weight":2, "Grade":65}}
        self.GPA = "0"
    def loadaverage(self):
        return self.GPA
    def get_Assignments(self):
        return self.Assignments
class LabelInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(
        self, parent, label, inp_cls, inp_args, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=label, anchor="w")
        self.input = inp_cls(self, **inp_args)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label.grid(sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
        self.input.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
student_directory = {"Honors Biology": ["John", "Bob"], "Nuclear Physics":["Simon", "Fred", "Larry"]}
#student_directory_set = set(student_directory.values())
student_repository = {}
for i in student_directory.values():
    for l in i:
        student_repository[l] = Pupil(l)
variables["Student"]=tk.StringVar()
variables["Subject"]=tk.StringVar()
def Action(e):
    Students.input.config(value=student_directory[Subject.input.get()])
    Students.input.current(0)
class Report():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = Students.input.get()
        self.subject = Subject.input.get()
        self.Report_Frame = tk.Frame(root).grid()
    def Load_Report(self):
        details = ""
        for Assignment in student_repository[self.name].get_Assignments():
            details += ("\n" + Assignment + " Score: " + str(student_repository[self.name].get_Assignments()[Assignment]["Grade"]))
        report_text = student_repository[self.name].Grade +"\n" + (details)
        Subject_Report = tk.Label(self.Report_Frame, text=report_text)
        Subject_Report.grid()


Subject = LabelInput(root, "Select Subject: ", ttk.Combobox, {"textvariable":variables["Subject"], "value":list(student_directory.keys())})
Subject.input.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Action)
Students = LabelInput(root, "Select Student: ", ttk.Combobox, {"textvariable":variables["Student"], "value":[]})
Subject.grid()
Students.grid()
Load_Button = tk.Button(root, text="Load Student Report", command=Report().Load_Report)
Load_Button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I select the contents of the first and then the second, and the click the button to "Load Student Report", I get a key error saying that the value of the second is ' '. Specifically in :

```
def Load_Report(self):
        details = ""
        for Assignment in student_repository[self.name].get_Assignments():
            details += ("\n" + Assignment + " Score: " + str(student_repository[self.name].get_Assignments()[Assignment]["Grade"]))
```

Comment: You need to move `self.name = Students.input.get()` and `self.subject = Subject.input.get()` from `Report.__init__()` to `Report.Load_Report()`.  Or change `command=Report().Load_Report` to `command=lambda: Report().Load_Report()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you acw1668

> "You need to move `self.name = Students.input.get()` and `self.subject = Subject.input.get()` from `Report.__init__()` to `Report.Load_Report()`. Or change `command=Report().Load_Report` to
> `command=lambda: Report().Load_Report()`.

-acw1668

The second half works well (the institution of the lambda function).